# AJAX простая отправка. консоль выдаёт ошибку на седьмой строке (data: str,). В чём ошибка?

Tags: ajax, отправка

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#check').click(function() {
        var str = $('#form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'data.php'
    data: str,
    success: function(html){
        $('#testDiv').append(html);
    }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
}
```

Comment: перед data запятую забыли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url: 'data.php'` - тут запятую поставь)